# How to get user photo from facebook

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, photo

When I register a user through facebook in spring-boot aplication, how to get his photo from facebook right away? I need get current user photo and set this photo to database

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After facebook Login success using Spring social library get the profile picture.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    public MainController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "feed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String feed(Model model) {

        if(connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        byte[] profilePicture = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfileImage();
        User userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
        model.addAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        PagedList<Post> userFeed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("userFeed", userFeed);
        return "feed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use without a Model?

Comment: @АндрійКотюга without model means ?

Comment: @АндрійКотюга You will get profile photo as byte[] and svae into file then you can process

Comment: Thanks, but where in this code will I use UserFacebookId

Comment: How I can use Facebook and ConnectionRepository? I can't inject they

Comment: @АндрійКотюга How you enable facebook sign in with your spring boot app ?
if using spring social above code will work - [more-detail](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-access-the-facebook-api-with-java-and-spring-boot/)